# I want to test whether a method is called within the lifecycle method componentDidMount, but I am getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a lifecycle method, `componentDidMount` that is calling a function, `setDateOnMount` which will be a spy within it. I am using jest and enzyme to test whether `setDateOnMount` runs or not, and I am getting an error that it is not called.

I have seen posts with the wrapper being called with `mount` rather than `shallow`, but I can't use mount because I am using the react-dates package, and it is conflicting with mount, where I cannot run it.

Here is my test:

```
test('componentDidMount should be called with setDateOnMount', () => {
        const setDateOnMount = jest.fn()
        const location = {
            state: undefined
        }
        const componentDidMount = jest.spyOn(MealSummary.prototype, 'componentDidMount')
        const wrapper = shallow(<MealSummary meals={meals} location={location} setDateOnMount={setDateOnMount} />)

        expect(componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(setDateOnMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)  //errors here that it is not called
    })
```

The partial component I am testing is here:

```
.
.
 componentDidMount() {
        this.setDateOnMount()
    }
.
.
...
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: I think that the main problem is the way that you are testing, you could think more about the behavior of your component from a user point of view what `this.setDateOnMount()` does? how it impacts the component? are you able to do an assertion over this behavior? it would make your test with more value and maybe easier.

Comment: Technically, I have tests that test what the date is set to within my component based on the setDateOnMount method.  Now, I simply want to test whether my componentDidMount runs the method or not, is this possible?

Comment: Please, provide the component. It’s unclear why you provide a mock as a prop.

Comment: Testing whether `componentDidMount` is called once would be akin to testing React itself, which is already well tested by the lib maintainers.

Comment: Here is the component https://github.com/altafmquadri/caloriEat/blob/master/src/components/MealSummary.js

and here is the test https://github.com/altafmquadri/caloriEat/blob/master/src/tests/components/MealSummary.test.js

Comment: Please include a [mcve] inside the question description.

Comment: I would suggest you do not test detailed implementation as the `componentDidMount ` what about if you do a simple refactor to use `useEffect`? what is the need to test the react life cycle as `expect(componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` ?

it is probably failing because of the `this` reference a workaround would be doing the bind of `componentDidMount` in the constructor. But it a strong-bad practice for your test.

Comment: I haven't studied hooks as of yet, I am trying to build this project to eventually add to a portfolio site, the `expect(componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalled(1)` will be removed.  I only used it to test whether it was running, since my assumption was that if componentDidMount runs then so should the spy setDateOnMount should run too.  As per reference to `this` I wrote another similar test for `componentWillUnmount` and it worked because I was passing in the spy referenced here https://github.com/altafmquadri/caloriEat/blob/master/src/tests/components/SearchFood.test.js

Answer (score 0):

To test if `setDateOnMount` is called or not, you can mock or spy on it:

- Spy :

```
test('componentDidMount should be called with setDateOnMount', () => {
  const setDateOnMount = jest.spyOn(MealSummary.prototype, 'setDateOnMount') // spy
  const wrapper = shallow(<MealSummary meals={[]} location={{state: undefined}}  />) // create
  expect(setDateOnMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // test
})
```

- Mock :

```
test('componentDidMount should be called with setDateOnMount', () => {
  const setDateOnMount = MealSummary.prototype.setDateOnMount = jest.fn() // mock
  const wrapper = shallow(<MealSummary meals={[]} location={{state: undefined}}  />) // create
  expect(setDateOnMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // test
})
```

Comment: I tried this, but I receive the following error `Cannot spy the setDateOnMount property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: @Altaf i rechecked it. i created a new component, and a new test, like this: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b1Te and it worked for me. so your problem is somewhere else. maybe you're using redux and you didn't include it in this question maybe `setDateOnMount` is a dynamic function, etc.

Comment: @Altaf also try mocking it instead of spying on it. updated the answer.